# WOL NIC active only when system is shutdown from CMD not from start -> shutdown

Tags: networking, windows-10, command-line, shutdown, wake-on-lan

My desktop (MB: Asus Maximus Hero VIII) seems to wake on LAN fine when shutting down via CMD using shutdown /t 0 but fails to WOL when i shut down using the Start -> Power -> shutdown. The network card shuts off as a result. OS is Windows 10 EDU

Comment: What's the power state of the NIC in the device property ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncheck "Turn on fast start-up" in the Windows Power Options.

[image: System Settings of the Windows Power Options]